# How can I have multiple angularjs material in the same page?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I create a page with `md-tab` it work perfectly

**detail.aspx**

```
<div ng-app="t" ng-controller="taCtrl">
    <md-content>
        <md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="">
            <md-tab label="IC_recap">
                <md-content class="md-padding">
                    <uc1:IC_recap runat="server" ID="IC_recap " />
                </md-content>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab label="État du IC_state">
                <md-content class="md-padding">
                    <uc1:IC_state runat="server" ID="IC_state" />
                </md-content>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab label="IC_Info ">
                <md-content class="md-padding">
                    <uc1:IC_Info runat="server" ID="IC_Info " />
                </md-content>
            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
     </md-content>
</div>
```

I wanted to create a search bar with angularjs materiel in my **masterpage.master**

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" id="DV_searchBar" class="autocompletedemoCustomTemplate" ng-app="MyApp">
    <md-content layout-padding="" layout="column">
    <form>
        <md-autocomplete md-dropdown-items="6" md-clear-button="false" id="custom-template"md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template"
            md-menu-container-class="custom-container"placeholder="Recherche" md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in query(searchText)">
            <md-item-template>
                <a href="{{item.url}}">
                <span class="item-title">
                    <span md-highlight-text="searchText" md-highlight-flags="i" style="color : #337ab7">{{item.nom}}</span>
                </span>
                    <span class="item-metadata">
                        <span>
                            <small style="color : gray;font-style:italic">{{item.obj}}</small>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </md-item-template>
        </md-autocomplete>
    </form>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

But when I add the search bar and I go on **detail.aspx** it doesn't show my `md-tab`
It is possible to add multiple angularjs material in the same page ? If it's possible how can I achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the issue comes from `ng-app="MyApp"` I can't have multiple ng-app in my project, just a global `ng-app`